# Is StatementBuilder for external use?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I was implementing a project with spring-data-jdbc and I found the Statement Builder API. I could this API be used for building native sql repositories?

Answer (score 0):

At this point the `StatementBuilder` API is considered internal and use outside Spring Data is not encouraged, because it might undergo breaking changes without the normal cycle of deprecation.

That said it is a pretty isolated piece of code with a friendly OSS license so in many cases it might be an acceptable risk to use it with the fallback plan to clone it into an own package should it change in a way that is not useable for you.

Comment: I really liked the API and found it a good alternative to mybatis or querydsl if it is used only as sql builder. Thanks for the answer.